# Backbone: Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am very new to backbone, and I am having an issue where the title variable is coming up as undefined in this simple example:

Here is the JS:

```
(function() {
    var Facet = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            title : ''
        }
    });

   var models = [
        new Facet({title: "Woah"}),
        new Facet({title: "Yeah"})
    ];

    var FacetView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'div',
        template:  _.template($("#facet_template").html()) ,
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

   _(models).each(function(model){
        $('aside#facets').append(new FacetView({model: model}));
    });

})();
// () means it is immediately invoked
```

Here is the HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Backbone.js"></script>

    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body id="page">
<h1>Example Search Page</h1>
    <aside id="facets" class="three columns">

    </aside>

    <div id="searchResults">

    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/template" id="facet_template">
    <label>
        <%= title %>
        <input type="checkbox" class="facet" />
    </label>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/TourFinder.js" defer="true"></script>
</html>
```

I am simply trying to loop through the array and pass those models into the view and render those views in the aside element on the page. I know I am missing something extremely simple here and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see anything that would give you that error. However, you don't want `el: 'div'` (that means "make my `el` the `$('div')[0]` element", not "create a new `<div>` as my `el`) and `.append(new FacetView({model: model}))` is a strange thing to do. You want something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DE5kW/

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant this:

```
_.each(models, function(model){
    $('aside#facets').append(new FacetView({model: model}));
});
```

Comment: `_(models).each(f)` and `_.each(models, f)` are the same thing.